# What is the system equation $f$ in Hamilton equation in $H=g+p^Tf$?

Tags: dynamic-programming, operations-research

*I am studying the Donald Kirk's book Introduction to Dynamic Programming.*

Suppose some integral $\int g dt$ that must be minimised. Then you are given some constraints. Hamilton equation is $H=g+p^T f$ where $f$ is the system equation.

Necessary conditions for Hamilton [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Usg01.png).

**Helper questions**

> 1. Does a question make any sense if the system equation is not specified explicitly?
> 2. What is the system equation $f$? It is easy to solve a question if the system equation is specified explicitly but otherwise I have hard time in figuring it out. What is it really?

Comment: This is not an  equation this is definition of Hamiltonian, here $g$ is $g(x,t,u)$ , $\dot x =f (x,t,u)$ , namely you have to optimize your integral with respect to control function $u$  subject to constraint  $\dot x =f (x,t,u)$ . Hamiltonian is used to define maximal principal.

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner Smart! $\dot x=f(x,t,u)$ is easier to remember than $\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}=f(x,t,u)$ even though meaning the same thing! But what does this mean in practise? Where are you getting this $f(x,t,u)$? I get lost if $f$ is not specified explicitly.

Comment: What about the third necessary condition for Hamiltonan $\frac{\partial H}{\partial u}=0$, where does it come from? $\dot x=f(x,t,u)$ is the first condition and $\dot p=\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}$ is the second.

Comment: ,I added my answer.

Comment: Researching this: found some awesome Harvard university material [here](http://users.physics.harvard.edu/~morii/phys151/lectures/Lecture18.pdf) and [some](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~shapiro/507/book3.pdf), deep stuff! Taking time read this and dig into!

Answer (score 2):

Typically we want to optimize the following functional
$$
\max_{u} \int_0^1 g(x(t),t,u(t)) dt
$$
subject to 
$$
\dot x = f(x,t,u), x(0)=x_0
$$
(bounds $0,1$ are taken for the sake of simplicity.
Since the  ODE cam be considered as a constraint between $\dot x$ and $x$ we can introduce a Lagrangian
$$
 L(x,t,\dot x,p,u)=g(x,t,u) + p (f(x,t,u) - \dot x)=H(x,p,t,u)-p\dot x ~~~~     (1)
$$
Now the idea is to look unconstrained optimum of 
$$
\int_0^1 L(x,t,\dot x,p,u) dt
$$
over $x(t),\dot x,$ $p(t)$ and $u$.
We know that when we vary functional we should come to Lagrangian equation
$$
\frac {\partial L} {\partial z}- \frac {d}{dt}\frac {\partial L} {\partial \dot z}=0 
$$
where $z$, can be $x,p,u$.
Applying this Lagrange equation  to (1) we can obtain:
$$
\dot x =f=\frac {\partial H}{\partial p},~ x(0)=x_0\\
\dot p=-\frac {\partial H}{\partial x}, ~ p(1)=0 \\
\frac {\partial H}{\partial u}=0
$$

Notice that this is not an intial value problem since $p$ is defined on the end of interval. This is why solving of such system is not an easy task. A Boundary condition for $p$ is obtained from variation conditions. They are different for the different type of functional.

Comment: +1! I love this writing style! What is $H$? What is Hamilton equation? I am puzzled by Hamilton equations because there looks to be many of them, want to learn this detail thoroughly...

Comment: could you please clarify this with definitions? @AlexanderVigodner can you set H to something?

Comment: $H=g+p f$ as it can be seen from (1)